# Microsoft.Identity.Client - "Use of Hard-coded Password" flaw

Tags: asp.net-core, veracode, microsoft.identity.web

There is an implicit reference to "[Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/)" in my asp .net core web api solution. Veracode has found several "Use of Hard-coded Password" flaws in this library (NuGet). Even after making an explicit reference to the latest version v4.55.0 of the library, the flaw prevails.

The below are the details of a flaw that was found in this library:
Source:
void !ctor(string, System.DateTimeOffset, System.DateTimeOffset, System.DateTimeOffset, System.Nullable, string, string, string): 11%

microsoft_identity_client_dll.Microsoft.Identity.Client.Cache.Items.MsalAccessTokenCacheItem

I checked the constructor in the class MsalAccessTokenCacheItem [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/main/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/Cache/Items/MsalAccessTokenCacheItem.cs) and I don't see any password or secret hardcoded. I don't know if this is a false positive.

Can anyone please advise if this is an issue in the library or something wrong with how it is used in my solution?

Comment: I check the source and also don't find any hardcode there, The library itself should not contain hard-coded passwords or secrets, especially in a widely-used and security-conscious library like Microsoft Authentication Library, It's better to post this issue in Asp.Net Core github, Maybe the MS developer can explain this

Comment: Many thanks. I guess this is a false positive. Just baffled a bit to see veracode finding issues like this.